# Android AlarmManager does not schedule

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I have a small Android Example with a Receiver registered in my Activity (so no receiver entry in AndroidManifest.xml)

But for some reason I do not receive anything.

```kotlin
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.getSystemService
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime

class Receiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("Test", "ACTION: ${intent?.action}")
    }
}

@ExperimentalTime
class Test: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val receiver = Receiver()
    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        alarmManager = getSystemService()!!

        val filter = IntentFilter()

        this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter)

        val intent = Intent(this, Receiver::class.java).apply {
            action = "TEST"
        }

        val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000

        Log.d("Test", "SCHEDULE: $timestamp")

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp, pIntent)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Intent(this, Receiver::class.java)` – Explicit `Intent`s do not work with dynamically-registered Receiver instances. If you really want to register dynamically, you could handle it with the action only; e.g., `val intent = Intent("TEST")` and `val filter = IntentFilter("TEST")`.

Comment: You are right!! Thank you ;-)